# start-stop-daemon: failed to start `/usr/bin/mongod'

Tags: linux, mongodb, alpine-linux

I have an alpine machine on my virtual machine and I want to install mongodb. I added the package for mongodb using "apk add mongodb". I started mongo daemon using command *mongod* in one terminal. Then opened another terminal with mongo shell using *mongo --disableJavaScriptJIT*. I tried adding files and reading them from the database and that worked fine. But when I do  sudo service mongodb restart  I got the following output.

```
     * Caching service dependencies ...                                       [ ok ]
     * Starting mongodb ...
     * start-stop-daemon: failed to start `/usr/bin/mongod'                   [ !! ]
     * ERROR: mongodb failed to start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to read the log file. I think that you’ll read here that mongodb doesn’t have rights to access some files. When you started it manually, you haven’t run it as user `mongodb`, have you…?

If this hypothesis is right, then the solution is to fix owner (and group) of the `/var/lib/mongodb` (recursively).

Comment: I just saw the logs and I realized that I didn't give proper rights and permissions to the folders. I fixed it. Thanks.